# NodeJS & Wikipedia API: different result from different hosts

Tags: linux, node.js, wikipedia

I have a project using NodeJS. It grabs data from the Wikipedia API, this works fine in ASCII languages but I recently added unicode support. 
Here is an example query:

```
https://zh.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=笔记本电脑
```

I use https.get to get the result.

This works fine on my laptop (Ubuntu Mate 15.04, kernel 4.0.5) which is currently in a different country than my server.
From my server (Ubuntu Server 14.04, kernel 3.13.0-37) it results in an empty response.

Using curl, I get the same correct respone on both hosts:

```
curl -v -L -G -d "search=笔记本电脑" https://zh.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch
```

Can someone help me troubleshoot this?

Edit: Response headers are different. The server version reports Bad Request, but why? See https://www.diffchecker.com/wh6hwyna

Comment: Does your app that issues requests in Node follow redirections, it would explain why it works fine using ASCII encoding and why it fails using results that might be available at another URL than requested.

Comment: Yes but the exact same source code does work on my laptop... So it must be a difference in my Linux configuration or a location issue, right?

Comment: Might be. Would it be possible to post the reponse headers received by your node apps on both your laptop and the server in order to compare them ?

Comment: Here is a compare of the 2 headers. The first is the working one. There are alot of differences... 
https://www.diffchecker.com/wh6hwyna

Comment: Are you sure that exactly the same code runs on both client and server ? Also are you sure that you use `https` URLs in both apps ?

Comment: Yes code is the same. However I may have narrowed it down a bit. Node version on the server is 0.12.4 (from src, default configure = no intl) and on my laptop was an older 0.10.x build (which I think includes internationalization support by default).
So I have built node 0.12.6 (latest) from src on my laptop with --with-intl=full-icu --download-all but it still doesn't work. But it most likely is something like this, I'm investigating further!

Comment: Created a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31232466/nodejs-https-get-with-unicode-string-results-in-bad-request